nginx configuration Secure Download got an error (404)
I followed the documentation to configure the download file, but I got an error 404.
documenttaion: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/secure_download/#secure-download-secret
this is my configation code.can you help me.
location /somefolder {
             secure_download on;

            secure_download_secret KgKLp;

             secure_download_path_mode file;

             if ($secure_download = "-1") {
                     rewrite /expired.html break;
              }

             if ($secure_download = "-2") {
                     rewrite /bad_hash.html break;
             }

             if ($secure_download = "-3") {
                     return 500;
             }

              rewrite ^(.*)/[0-9a-zA-Z]*/[0-9a-zA-Z]*$ $1 break;  
    }`

I have a file in my document root  under the path /somefolder/protected.html.
I create the url with  the following code:
`   public static void main(String[] args) {
    var str = "/somefolder/protected.html/KgKLp/1715158623";

    MD5 md5 = MD5.create();
    var digest = md5.digestHex(str);

    var url = "/somefolder/protected.html/" + digest + "/1715158623";

    System.out.printf(url); ///somefolder/protected.html/ffa42944fd9de29db2e4458d509873d2/1715158623

}`

I request the url(http://...*:8080/somefolder/protected.html/ffa42944fd9de29db2e4458d509873d2/1715158623)
and i get an error 404. I dont know why. can you help me.
